# Traefik Ingress Controller does not set Address in EKS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik

I have set up an EKS cluster and I need the pods I am creating in the Kubernetes to have a domain. Therefore, I have set up Traefik Ingress Controller and external-dns tools. To be noted, all policies and rules are applied correctly in the AWS and also in the Kubernetes cluster but also in the external-dns.

When I am setting up the Traefik, it normally creates the load balancer in the subnet I have configured to and assigns it to the traefik-operator. I am able to view the created load balancer also in the console of AWS.

[image]

I have tried all possible annotations and arguments in the traefik operator but still my ingress has not set any address.

[image]

If I describe an ingress controller I have these:
[image]

I am not sure if the error with the default backend may causing the problem.

The logs of the external-dns are:

[image]

And the logs of the traefik-operator are:
[image]

This is my traefik yaml file:

```
# Default values for Traefik
image:
  # -- Traefik image host registry
  registry: docker.io
  # -- Traefik image repository
  repository: traefik
  # -- defaults to appVersion
  tag: ""
  # -- Traefik image pull policy
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

# -- Add additional label to all resources
commonLabels: {}

#
# Configure the deployment
#
deployment:
  # -- Enable deployment
  enabled: true
  # -- Deployment or DaemonSet
  kind: Deployment
  # -- Number of pods of the deployment (only applies when kind == Deployment)
  replicas: 1
  # -- Number of old history to retain to allow rollback (If not set, default Kubernetes value is set to 10)
  # revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  # -- Amount of time (in seconds) before Kubernetes will send the SIGKILL signal if Traefik does not shut down
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
  # -- The minimum number of seconds Traefik needs to be up and running before the DaemonSet/Deployment controller considers it available
  minReadySeconds: 0
)
  annotations: {}
  # -- Additional deployment labels (e.g. for filtering deployment by custom labels)
  labels: {}
  # -- Additional pod annotations (e.g. for mesh injection or prometheus scraping)
  podAnnotations: {}
  # -- Additional Pod labels (e.g. for filtering Pod by custom labels)
  podLabels: {}
  # -- Additional containers (e.g. for metric offloading sidecars)
  additionalContainers: []

  additionalVolumes: []
    # - name: dsdsocket
    #   hostPath:
    #     path: /var/run/statsd-exporter
  # -- Additional initContainers (e.g. for setting file permission as shown below)
  initContainers: []

  # -- Use process namespace sharing
  shareProcessNamespace: false
  # -- Custom pod DNS policy. Apply if `hostNetwork: true`
  # dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
  dnsConfig: {}

  imagePullSecrets: []
    # - name: myRegistryKeySecretName
  # -- Pod lifecycle actions
  lifecycle: {}

podDisruptionBudget:
  enabled: false

ingressClass:
  enabled: true
  isDefaultClass: true
  # name: my-custom-class

# Traefik experimental features
experimental:
  #This value is no longer used, set the image.tag to a semver higher than 3.0, e.g. "v3.0.0-beta3"
  #v3:
    # -- Enable traefik version 3
  #  enabled: false
  plugins:
    # -- Enable traefik experimental plugins
    enabled: false
  kubernetesGateway:
    # -- Enable traefik experimental GatewayClass CRD
    enabled: false
    gateway:
      # -- Enable traefik regular kubernetes gateway
      enabled: true
    # certificate:


## Create an IngressRoute for the dashboard
ingressRoute:
  dashboard:
    # -- Create an IngressRoute for the dashboard
    enabled: true
    # -- Additional ingressRoute annotations (e.g. for kubernetes.io/ingress.class)
    annotations: {}
    # -- Additional ingressRoute labels (e.g. for filtering IngressRoute by custom labels)
    labels: {}
    # -- The router match rule used for the dashboard ingressRoute
    matchRule: PathPrefix(`/dashboard`) || PathPrefix(`/api`)
    # -- Specify the allowed entrypoints to use for the dashboard ingress route, (e.g. traefik, web, websecure).
    # By default, it's using traefik entrypoint, which is not exposed.
    # /!\ Do not expose your dashboard without any protection over the internet /!\
    entryPoints: ["traefik"]
    # -- Additional ingressRoute middlewares (e.g. for authentication)
    middlewares: []
    # -- TLS options (e.g. secret containing certificate)
    tls: {}

updateStrategy:
  # -- Customize updateStrategy: RollingUpdate or OnDelete
  type: RollingUpdate
  rollingUpdate:
    maxUnavailable: 0
    maxSurge: 1

readinessProbe:
  # -- The number of consecutive failures allowed before considering the probe as failed.
  failureThreshold: 1
  # -- The number of seconds to wait before starting the first probe.
  initialDelaySeconds: 2
  # -- The number of seconds to wait between consecutive probes.
  periodSeconds: 10
  # -- The minimum consecutive successes required to consider the probe successful.
  successThreshold: 1
  # -- The number of seconds to wait for a probe response before considering it as failed.
  timeoutSeconds: 2
livenessProbe:
  # -- The number of consecutive failures allowed before considering the probe as failed.
  failureThreshold: 3
  # -- The number of seconds to wait before starting the first probe.
  initialDelaySeconds: 2
  # -- The number of seconds to wait between consecutive probes.
  periodSeconds: 10
  # -- The minimum consecutive successes required to consider the probe successful.
  successThreshold: 1
  # -- The number of seconds to wait for a probe response before considering it as failed.
  timeoutSeconds: 2

providers:
  kubernetesCRD:
    # -- Load Kubernetes IngressRoute provider
    enabled: true
    # -- Allows IngressRoute to reference resources in namespace other than theirs
    allowCrossNamespace: true
    # -- Allows to reference ExternalName services in IngressRoute
    allowExternalNameServices: true
    # -- Allows to return 503 when there is no endpoints available
    allowEmptyServices: false
    # ingressClass: traefik-internal
    # labelSelector: environment=production,method=traefik
    # -- Array of namespaces to watch. If left empty, Traefik watches all namespaces.
    namespaces: []
      # - "default"

  kubernetesIngress:
    # -- Load Kubernetes Ingress provider
    enabled: true
    # -- Allows to reference ExternalName services in Ingress
    allowExternalNameServices: true
    # -- Allows to return 503 when there is no endpoints available
    allowEmptyServices: true
    ingressClass: traefik-internal
    # labelSelector: environment=production,method=traefik
    # -- Array of namespaces to watch. If left empty, Traefik watches all namespaces.
    namespaces: []
      # - "default"
    # IP used for Kubernetes Ingress endpoints
    publishedService:
      enabled: true
additionalArguments:
- "--log.level=DEBUG"
- "--providers.kubernetesingress.ingressendpoint.publishedservice=traefik/dds-traefik-operator"
volumes: []
# - name: public-cert
#   mountPath: "/certs"
#   type: secret
# - name: '{{ printf "%s-configs" .Release.Name }}'
#   mountPath: "/config"
#   type: configMap

# -- Additional volumeMounts to add to the Traefik container
additionalVolumeMounts: []
  # -- For instance when using a logshipper for access logs
  # - name: traefik-logs
  #   mountPath: /var/log/traefik

logs:
  general:
    # -- By default, the logs use a text format (common), but you can
    # also ask for the json format in the format option
    # format: json
    # By default, the level is set to ERROR.
    # -- Alternative logging levels are DEBUG, PANIC, FATAL, ERROR, WARN, and INFO.
    level: DEBUG
  access:
    # -- To enable access logs
    enabled: false

    # -- https://docs.traefik.io/observability/access-logs/#filtering
    filters: {}
    fields:
      general:
        # -- Available modes: keep, drop, redact.
        defaultmode: keep
        # -- Names of the fields to limit.
        names: {}
          ## Examples:
          # ClientUsername: drop
      headers:
        # -- Available modes: keep, drop, redact.
        defaultmode: drop
        # -- Names of the headers to limit.
        names: {}
          ## Examples:


metrics:
  ## -- Prometheus is enabled by default.
  ## -- It can be disabled by setting "prometheus: null"
  prometheus:
    # -- Entry point used to expose metrics.
    entryPoint: metrics


# -- Global command arguments to be passed to all traefik's pods
globalArguments:
  - "--global.checknewversion"
  - "--global.sendanonymoususage"
  - "--providers.kubernetesingress.ingressendpoint.publishedservice=traefik/dds-traefik-operator"

additionalArguments: [
  --providers.kubernetesingress.ingressclass=traefik-internal,
  --providers.kubernetesingress.ingressendpoint.publishedservice=traefik/dds-traefik-operator,
  --log.level=DEBUG
]
#  - "--providers.kubernetesingress.ingressclass=traefik-internal"
#  - "--log.level=DEBUG"

# -- Environment variables to be passed to Traefik's binary
env:
  - name: POD_NAME
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.name
  - name: POD_NAMESPACE
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.namespace

envFrom: []
# - configMapRef:
#     name: config-map-name
# - secretRef:
#     name: secret-name

ports:
  traefik:
    port: 9000
   
    expose: false
    # -- The exposed port for this service
    exposedPort: 9000
    # -- The port protocol (TCP/UDP)
    protocol: TCP
  web:
    ## -- Enable this entrypoint as a default entrypoint. When a service doesn't explicitly set an entrypoint it will only use this entrypoint.
    # asDefault: true
    port: 8000
    # hostPort: 8000
    # containerPort: 8000
    expose: true
    exposedPort: 80

    protocol: TCP
    
  websecure:
    ## -- Enable this entrypoint as a default entrypoint. When a service doesn't explicitly set an entrypoint it will only use this entrypoint.
    # asDefault: true
    port: 8443
    # hostPort: 8443
    # containerPort: 8443
    expose: true
    exposedPort: 443

    protocol: TCP
   
    http3:
      enabled: false

    tls:
      enabled: true
      # this is the name of a TLSOption definition
      options: ""
      certResolver: ""
      domains: []

    middlewares: []
  metrics:
    # -- When using hostNetwork, use another port to avoid conflict with node exporter:
    # https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/wiki/Default-port-allocations
    port: 9100
    expose: false
    # -- The exposed port for this service
    exposedPort: 9100
    # -- The port protocol (TCP/UDP)
    protocol: TCP


tlsOptions: {}


tlsStore: {}

service:
  enabled: true
  ## -- Single service is using `MixedProtocolLBService` feature gate.
  ## -- When set to false, it will create two Service, one for TCP and one for UDP.
  single: true
  type: LoadBalancer
  # -- Additional annotations applied to both TCP and UDP services (e.g. for cloud provider specific config)
  annotations: {
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb",
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true",
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: "instance",
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: "traefik.domain",
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true",
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: subnet-22, subnet-33
  }
  annotationsTCP: {}
  annotationsUDP: {}
  labels: {}
  spec: {}
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
  externalIPs: []


autoscaling:
  # -- Create HorizontalPodAutoscaler object.
  enabled: false


persistence:
  # -- Enable persistence using Persistent Volume Claims
  # ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/
  # It can be used to store TLS certificates, see `storage` in certResolvers
  enabled: false
  name: data
#  existingClaim: ""
  accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  size: 128Mi
  # storageClass: ""
  # volumeName: ""
  path: /data
  annotations: {}
  # -- Only mount a subpath of the Volume into the pod
  # subPath: ""

# -- Certificates resolvers configuration
certResolvers: {}

hostNetwork: false

# -- Whether Role Based Access Control objects like roles and rolebindings should be created
rbac:
  enabled: true
  # If set to false, installs ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding so Traefik can be used across namespaces.
  # If set to true, installs Role and RoleBinding. Providers will only watch target namespace.
  namespaced: false
  # Enable user-facing roles
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#user-facing-roles
  # aggregateTo: [ "admin" ]

# -- Enable to create a PodSecurityPolicy and assign it to the Service Account via RoleBinding or ClusterRoleBinding
podSecurityPolicy:
  enabled: false

# -- The service account the pods will use to interact with the Kubernetes API
serviceAccount:
  # If set, an existing service account is used
  # If not set, a service account is created automatically using the fullname template
  name: ""

# -- Additional serviceAccount annotations (e.g. for oidc authentication)
serviceAccountAnnotations: {}

# -- The resources parameter defines CPU and memory requirements and limits for Traefik's containers.
resources: {}
  # requests:
  #   cpu: "100m"
  #   memory: "50Mi"
  # limits:
  #   cpu: "300m"
  #   memory: "150Mi"

# -- This example pod anti-affinity forces the scheduler to put traefik pods
# -- on nodes where no other traefik pods are scheduled.
# It should be used when hostNetwork: true to prevent port conflicts
affinity: {}

nodeSelector: {}
# -- Tolerations allow the scheduler to schedule pods with matching taints.
tolerations: []
# -- You can use topology spread constraints to control
# how Pods are spread across your cluster among failure-domains.
topologySpreadConstraints: []

priorityClassName: ""

# -- Set the container security context
# -- To run the container with ports below 1024 this will need to be adjusted to run as root
securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop: [ALL]
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false

podSecurityContext:
  # /!\ When setting fsGroup, Kubernetes will recursively change ownership and
  # permissions for the contents of each volume to match the fsGroup. This can
  # be an issue when storing sensitive content like TLS Certificates /!\
  # fsGroup: 65532
  # -- Specifies the policy for changing ownership and permissions of volume contents to match the fsGroup.
  fsGroupChangePolicy: "OnRootMismatch"
  # -- The ID of the group for all containers in the pod to run as.
  runAsGroup: 65532
  # -- Specifies whether the containers should run as a non-root user.
  runAsNonRoot: true
  # -- The ID of the user for all containers in the pod to run as.
  runAsUser: 65532

#
# -- Extra objects to deploy (value evaluated as a template)
#
# In some cases, it can avoid the need for additional, extended or adhoc deployments.
# See #595 for more details and traefik/tests/values/extra.yaml for example.
extraObjects: []
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have almost tried everything with no luck.
The main goal is to set the address of the ingress to the load balancer that was assigned to traefik service as I can understand in order to automatically create domains in the Route53 of AWS using the external-dns tool.